# How to shuffle such that two same elements are not together?

Tags: matlab, loops, shuffle

I have a string containing several elements, some identical and some unique. I want my code to check every 2 following elements in my string and if they're equal, it should call a function `ShuffleString`, where the input variable (`randomize`) is the string itself, that will re-shuffle the string in a new position. Then, the script should re-check every 2 following elements in the string again until no two identical elements appear next to each other.

---

I have done the following:
My function file `ShuffleString`  works fine. The input variable `randomize`, as stated earlier, contains the same elements as `MyString` but in a different order, as this was needed on an unrelated matter earlier in the script.

```
function [MyString] = ShuffleString(randomize)
MyString = [];
while length(randomize) > 0
    S = randi(length(randomize), 1);
    MyString = [MyString, randomize(S)];
    randomize(S) = [];
end
```

The script doesn't work as intended. Right now it looks like this:

```
MyString = ["Cat" "Dog" "Mouse" "Mouse" "Dog" "Hamster" "Zebra" "Obama"...
    "Dog" "Fish" "Salmon" "Turkey"];

randomize = MyString;
while(1)
    for Z = 1:length(MyString)
        if Z < length(MyString)
            Q = Z+1;
        end
        if isequal(MyString{Z},MyString{Q})
            [MyString]=ShuffleString(randomize)
            continue;
        end
    end
end
```

It just seems to reshuffle the string an infinite amount of times. What's wrong with this and how can I make it work?

Comment: because you're using an infinite loop? `while(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an infinite `while` loop that has no way to break and hence it keeps iterating.

Here is a simpler way:
Use the third output argument of the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function to get the elements in numeric form for easier processing. Apply [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) on it to check if consecutive elements are same. If there is any occurrence of same consecutive elements, the output of `diff` will give at least one zero which when applied with [negated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) will return [`true`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/true.html) to continue the loop and vice versa. At the end, use the shuffled indices/numeric representation of the strings obtained after the loop to index the first output argument of `unique` (which was calculated earlier). So the script will be:

```
MyString = ["Cat" "Dog" "Mouse" "Mouse" "Dog" "Hamster" "Zebra" "Obama"...
    "Dog" "Fish" "Salmon" "Turkey"]; %Given string array
[a,~,c] = unique(MyString);%finding unique elements and their indices
while ~all(diff(c))        %looping until there are no same strings together
    c = ShuffleString(c);  %shuffling the unique indices 
end
MyString = a(c);           %using the shuffled indices to get the required string array
```

For the function `ShuffleString`, a better way would be to use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html). Your version of function works but it keeps changing the size of the arrays `MyString` and `randomize` and hence [adversely affects the performance and memory usage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Here is a simpler way:

```
function MyString = ShuffleString(MyString)
MyString = MyString(randperm(numel(MyString)));
end
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Works perfect and just what I wanted, thank you so much!